Hotkey for equal sign and colon alignment?
I joined a company recently where they seem to like to align the = and : on consecutive lines in python, e.g., instead of
a = 0
bb = 2
ccc = 3

they do
a   = 0
bb  = 2
ccc = 3

and likewise for :. I find it very tedious to have to do this for every line when the spacing needs to be adjusted. Is there a hotkey for doing this in standard text editors? I most use VSCode and sublime.

For VSCode, you can use extensions like "Python" by Microsoft, which provides various formatting options including alignment of assignments. You can also try extensions like "Python Docstring Generator" or "Auto Aligner" for more specific alignment functionalities.

The "Simple Alignment" extension seems to allow that, but it's a horrible convention (it also violates PEP-8, specifically rule E221 of Flake8). What happens one variable is i and the other is really_long_and_descriptive_variable_name?

"Many projects have their own coding style guidelines. In the event of any conflicts, such project-specific guides take precedence for that project."

@juanpa.arrivillaga I am not suggesting that they should not follow the guideline. Quite the contrary, I recommended a tool that can supposedly help doing that. I'm merely pointing out that it's a horrible guideline.

@Selcuk, why is it a horrible guideline, just because it's one of Guido's "pet peeves", or for some actual reason?  I find the aligned version easier to read. Indeed, it's very popular to align equations at the equal sign in math.

@Selcuk I don't think this convention is religiously followed, and I typically don't follow it when I'm writing new code. But when I edit existing code and there's already 30 lines with that convention, and I add a 31st line that doesn't adhere to it, it looks weird

the reason why I don't follow it is because I'm lazy :). I don't have any other reason for not following it and i haven't seen a case where really_long_and_descriptive_variable_name existed in this codebase (quite frankly it's the opposite with short acronyms that no one new to the codebase know what it means)

@Joe agreed. I do that in math as well, especially when writing proofs in latex. i feel like this is a "should i cater to the reader or the dev" debate

this package should do the trick : https://packagecontrol.io/packages/VAlign

This behavior goes against python's automatic formatting guidelines, but you can accomplish it via a extension in VSCode.
You could open your extension store and search for Better Align.
In the example you provided, you could check the equal sign, and open your  Command Palette(Ctrl+Shift+P) and type "Align"(default shortcuts is Alt + A).


